# Can I create a dummy socket.io client inside the socket.io server in node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

We are writing an application which needs a dummy user as a socket.io client with the user, which will act as a dummy user to send and receive messages. Each user will have the dummy client that should be able to send message to client (User).

This is my server connection handler. I want to create a socket.io client here, as new client is connected on server. How can I develop this?

```
   self.socket.on('connection', function(client){
      //here I want to create a separate module for handling dummy users 
      // for sending and receiving message.

    });
```

How will I include Socket.io Client Script in node? Updating the client I write on server.

```
exports.init=function(){
    var socket = new io.Socket(config.host, {port: config.port, rememberTransport: false});
    // when connected, clear out display
    socket.on('connect',function() {
        console.log('dummy user connected');
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
        console.log('disconnected dummy');
    });
    socket.on('message', function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
    socket.connect();
    return socket;
};
```

Here I am creating the client

```
if (message._command=='login') {
        console.log('creating client of '+sessionId);
        var socket=client.init();
        
        console.log(socket);
    }
```

This console is printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We are writing an application which needs a dummy user as a socket.io client with the user, which will act as a dummy user to send and receive messages.

If you want to simulate browser clients through the server which are connected to your socket.io server you can try to use some of the node.js socket.io clients, such as [node-socket.io-client](https://github.com/saschagehlich/node-socket.io-client) or [Socket.IO-node-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node-client).

Comment: i created a dummy client when a socket.io sends the login command , but i can't do console.log in the client , on server to check what messages are coming ?

Comment: I think that server and dummy clients should be run as separated programs. For example your server would run just as you intent (serving incoming requests from clients) and in program for dummy clients you would just create new instance of the client(s) and connect them to your running server address.

Comment: how can i  debug in dummy  client ?

Comment: Since it would be running as a standalone program simulating browser clients you should be able to debug it the same way as a normal node.js program.

Comment: i updated the question with the code i put for client , and any console.log is not getting printed .

Comment: when i create the client at  console.log('creating client of '+sessionId); this and socket is getting printed but not  console of client , why ?

Comment: I just tested the node-socket.io-client and it looks like it's not compatible with the current version of socket.io which is giving me "unknown transport" error. The other module looks like it's not yet ready for some serious testing either :/.

Comment: I am using socket.io 0.6 only

Comment: problem was in my declaration of config , not given the var , now its running

Comment: now i have upgraded the socket.io 0.8.7 and this client is not working with that i think , what uh say