# how to get session id of socket.io client in Client

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I want to get session id of client in my socket.io client.

here is my socket.io client :

```
var socket = new io.Socket(config.host, {port: config.port, rememberTransport: false});
    // when connected, clear out display
    socket.on('connect',function() {
        console.log('dummy user connected');
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
    socket.connect();
    return socket;
```

I want to get session id of this client , how can i get that ?

Comment: got by socket.transport.sessionid.

Comment: socket.sessionid or socket.transport.sessid

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket.io custom client ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702461/socket-io-custom-client-id)

Answer (score 45):

Have a look at [my primer](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/) on exactly this topic.

**UPDATE:**

```
var sio = require('socket.io'),
    app = require('express').createServer();

app.listen(8080);
sio = sio.listen(app);

sio.on('connection', function (client) {
  console.log('client connected');

  // send the clients id to the client itself.
  client.send(client.id);

  client.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
});
```

Comment: Please tell how to get session id in client ?

Comment: It's in the cookie. Either grab it from there (``document.cookie``) or explicitly send it to the client from the server.

Comment: I checked in document.cookie in the one client conencted but it is blank .

Comment: What session id are we talking about?

Comment: The sessionid of a client in socket.io

Comment: It is client.id. Send it to the client using client.send if you want the client to know it's own id. See update.

Comment: I have created a client inside the server when login message arrive , how to get sessionid of that client

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966492/can-i-create-a-dummy-socket-io-client-inside-the-socket-io-server-in-node-js , See the yojimbo87 answer

Comment: got by socket.transport.sessionid.

Comment: socket.socket.sessionid, or as in this example client.socket.sessionid

Comment: Now that I am thinking about this.... why not just set the store for the cookies and the store for the socket to the same store?

Comment: socket.sessionid seems to have disappered for socket.io version 1.0.. I see the session ID looking token under io.engine.id. Maybe it's renamed?

Answer (score 44):

On socket.io >=1.0, after the connect event has triggered:

```
var socket = io('localhost');
var id = socket.io.engine.id
```

Comment: I could only get it after `socket.on 'connect'`

Comment: @webjay yeah, property is only assigned on connect event, not before.

Comment: so you set the engine now how you grab it from server?

Comment: that worked for me! did NOT have to use it on socket.on 'connect'

Answer (score 10):

### *** Please Note: as of v0.9 the `set` and `get` API has been deprecated ***

The following code should only be used for version ***socket.io < 0.9***

**See**: http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/

It can be done through the handshake/authorization mechanism.

```
var cookie = require('cookie');
io.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
    // check if there's a cookie header
    if (data.headers.cookie) {
        // if there is, parse the cookie
        data.cookie = cookie.parse(data.headers.cookie);
        // note that you will need to use the same key to grad the
        // session id, as you specified in the Express setup.
        data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];
    } else {
       // if there isn't, turn down the connection with a message
       // and leave the function.
       return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
    // accept the incoming connection
    accept(null, true);
});
```

All the attributes, that are assigned to the data object are now accessible through the handshake attribute of the socket.io connection object.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('sessionID ' + socket.handshake.sessionID);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same problem/question and solved it like this (only client code):

```
var io = io.connect('localhost');

io.on('connect', function () {
    console.log(this.socket.sessionid);
});
```

Comment: This returned 'undefined' for me with socket.io 1.4.5

Comment: thanx for the information, i guess socket.io changed a bit since 2013 :) - i will test it soon and update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

On Server side

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log(socket.id)
})
```

On Client side

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(socket.id, socket.io.engine.id, socket.json.id)
})
```

If `socket.id`, doesn't work, make sure you call it in `on('connect')` or after the connection.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log(socket.io.engine.id);
});
```

did not work for me. However

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log(io().id);
});
```

did work for me. Hopefully this is helpful for people who also had issues with getting the id. I use Socket IO >= 1.0, by the way.

Comment: The event function receives a variable, which has what you seek: ```io.on('connection', function(client) { console.log(client.id); });```

Answer (score 0):

Try from your code 
socket.socket.sessionid
ie.

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
alert(socket.socket.sessionid);
  var sendBtn= document.getElementById('btnSend');
  sendBtn.onclick= function(){
var userId=document.getElementById('txt1').value;
var userMsg = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
socket.emit('sendto',{username: userId, message: userMsg});
};

  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
  socket.on('message',function(data){ console.log(data);});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way.

```
                var socket = io.connect('http://...');
                console.log(socket.Socket.sessionid);
```