# Socket.io Detect when client disconnects

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm writing an application where I open up a socket when a user visits my site, record information by sending data over the socket while the user is on the site, and store the information in a database once the user leaves the site.

The problem I am currently facing is that while I can detect when a socket disconnects from my server, I don't know which socket corresponds to what information, so I don't know what information to store into the database.

Below is where I believe I need to put in code

```
socket.on('disconnect',function() {
  //insert data corresponding to current socket into database
  console.log('The client has disconnected!');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702461/socket-io-custom-client-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to keep some kind of state associated with the socket connection. I think what you are looking for is socket.io sessions.

Plenty of examples around on the net, this thread has a lot of good information: [socket.io and session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641053/socket-io-and-session)

I found this particularly usefull: http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to keep my app as simple as possible though. Is there anyway I can use sessions or assign ids to my sockets without using express?

Comment: I remember having this exact same issue, I was not able to find anything that worked. I am don't think there are any popular implementations that do not require express/connect.