# socket.io / parameters on connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

In my node.js / Express.js app, I need to pass parameters with the socket.io connection (saw that in another post).

On client side, I have something like :

**edit**

```
var socket = io.connect('/image/change', {query:"name=my_img_name"});
var siofu = new SocketIOFileUpload(socket);

siofu.listenOnInput(document.getElementById("change_image_inpt"));
```

On server side :

**edit**

```
io.of('/image/change')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('log input param : ' + socket.handshake.query.name);
});
```

But nothing in the console.

Is there another way to achieve that ?

**edit2**

This is the full code for client :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// icon_action_modal
$('.icon_actions').on('click', function() {
    // set icon preview
    $('#icon_action_modal_icon_preview').html('<img src="/upload/icon/' + $(this).data('icon') + '.png" />');

    // set icon to delete
    $('#icon_name').val($(this).data('icon'));

    // set Change icon socket
    var socket = io.connect('/icon_sets/change', {query:"name=my_img_name"});
    var siofu = new SocketIOFileUpload(socket);

    siofu.listenOnInput(document.getElementById("change_icon"));

    // Do something when a file is uploaded
    siofu.addEventListener("complete", function () {
        $('.overlay').hide();
    });

    // display loader window
    socket.on('displayOverlay', displayOverlay);

    // display
    socket.on('displayIconImage', function (data) {
        $('#iconset_render').append('<div class="icon"><img src="' + data.path + '" /></div>');
    });

    socket.on('setIconsetArray', function (data) {
        var iconset = ($('#iconset_array').val()) ? JSON.parse($('#iconset_array').val()) : [];

        iconset.push(data.iconName);

        $('#iconset_array').val(JSON.stringify(iconset));

        deleteIcon($('#icon_name').val());

        // close modal
        $('#icon_action_modal').modal('hide');
    });

});

$('#icon_action_modal_delete_icon').on('click', function() {
    deleteIcon($('#icon_name').val());

    // close modal
    $('#icon_action_modal').modal('hide');
});

}); // end document.ready
```

And the full code for server side :

```
io.of('/icon_sets/change')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('log input param : ' + socket.handshake.query.name);
    functions.socketImageTransfer(socket, 'icon', 65, 65);
});
```

With the `socketImageTransfer` function :

```
module.exports.socketImageTransfer = function(socket, type, width, height, name) {

var socketioFileUploadServer    = require('socketio-file-upload');   // upload files by socket
var config                      = require(__dirname + '/config/config.json');
var easyimg                     = require('easyimage');                 // crop - resize image
var fs                          = require('fs');                        // file system access

// Make an instance of socketioFileUploadServer and listen on this socket:
var uploader = new socketioFileUploadServer();
uploader.dir = config.tmpDir;
uploader.listen(socket);

// Do something when a file is saved:
uploader.on('saved', function (event) {

    console.log('Original ' + type + ' saved');

    // resize and rename image with a unique id
    var newName;

    if (!name) {
        newName = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + '_' + type + '.png';
    } else {
        newName = name;
    }

    var fileName = event.file.name.replace(/ /g, '_');

    easyimg.rescrop({src: config.tmpDir + fileName, dst: config.uploadDir + type + '/' + newName, width: width, height: height}, function (err, image) {

        if (err) return console.log(err);

        console.log(type + ' resized and cropped: ' + image.width + ' x ' + image.height);

        // image is uploaded - resized - croped, now display it
        socket.emit('display' + ucfirst(type) + 'Image', {path: '/upload/'+ type + '/' + newName});

        // remove original from file system
        fs.unlink(config.tmpDir + fileName, function () {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Original ' + type + ' removed');
        });

        // additionnal action
        switch(type) {
            case 'icon':
                // send path to generate iconset_json
                socket.emit('setIconsetArray', {iconName: newName});
                break;
        }

    });

});

uploader.on('start', function (event) {
    console.log('Client start upload');
    socket.emit('displayOverlay');
});

// Error handler:
uploader.on('error', function (event) {
    console.log("Error from uploader", event);
});

};
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: If there is nothing in the console, your `connection` handler doesn't fire at all, because at least `undefined` should be in the console. Probably you have an error in some other place along with an error I've described in my answer.

Comment: Your code seems to be working except one thing: you declare `socket`, but pass `socket2` to `SocketIOFileUpload` constructor.

Comment: Yes, sorry, In my code the real name of the socket is `socket2. But as I said in your answer, this code is executed BEFORE I want ... it's executed when I start the server. And at this time, the client file who content the socket code is not yes included...

Comment: I believe it's executed on server start because you have an opened page in your browser, and Socket.IO tries to reconnect each `n` seconds. When server started, reconnect becomes successful and your `connection` handler fires (which usually fires when connection between client and server successfully established). It's strange that `console.log` outputs `underfined`. I tried your code and for me in works fine with both Socket.IO 0.9 and 1.0. Can you show your full code, because I think the problem is in other place.

Comment: Did you try with socket.io file upload module ? Maybe the problem is with this package ... I use socket.io 0.9. Please, see the post update. I've added the full client - server code. I've not added the HTML part. It's just a modal window opened by a click on an image you want to change. `<a title="Icon Actions" class="icon_actions" data-toggle="modal" href="#icon_action_modal" data-icon="<%= icon %>">`. TY for your help

Comment: Strange :/ this code works for me. I can see `log input param : my_img_name` in my console. Take a look at my server side code at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gp2NEksf). Probably this code differs from yours.

Comment: By the way, how do you serve `/siofu/client.js` file?

Comment: It's just an EJS include script in my layout from the view. `<% script('/siofu/client.js') %>` these scripts are included before the `</body>` close tag. I created a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FTrn6k7P) post to show you the complete server side. Ty for your time & your help

Comment: I edited my answer. See changes below

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, there is.

1) `query` is like `GET` parameters, so replace `"param:value"` with `"param=value"` (if you want to pass multiple parameters, do it as you usually do with URL: `param=value&some_other_param=test`)

2) There is an easier and more reliable (because there is no risk to access an undefined property of `handshaken` object) way to get query parameter inside `connection` handler:

```
console.log(socket.handshake.query.param);
```

***Edit:***

After learning your full code I guess I figured out what causes the problem. The problem is that you probably misunderstood the main idea of Socket.IO namespaces.

I guess you have multiple Socket.IO connections (`io.connect` calls) within one page, right? Usually a single connection is enough. Your mistake is that you call `io.connect` on mouse event, but you should call in once on `document.ready`, and then just `emit`ting.

Take a look at the following code (client side):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('', {query: 'name=something'});

    // [...]

    socket.on('some_event_from_server', function(data, cb) {});

    // [...]

    $('#someButton').click(function() {
        socket.emit('markers_add', {some: 'data'});  //send `markers_add` message to server within main namespace
    });

    $('#someOtherButton').click(function() {
        socket.emit('icon_sets_add', {some: 'thing'}, function(response) {
            //server may response to this request. see server side code below
        });
    });
});
```

Server side code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {  //connection handler of main namespace
    socket.on('markers_add', function(data) { /* ... */  });
    socket.on('icon_sets_add', function(data, cb) {
        // do something
        cb({some: 'response'});
    });

    // [...]

    socket.emit('some_event_from_server', {});  //server sends a message to a client

    //BTW, now it should be OK:
    console.log(socket.handshake.query.name);
});
```

If you have one namespace it should work. I don't know actually if it was a bug of Socket.IO or a result of improper usage of namespaces, but modifying code to make just one namespace should do the trick. <strike>So in your case you don't have to pass query parameters when handshaking at all.</strike> Actually you have to use query parameter if you want to make your app more secure. See http://wlkns.co/node-js/socket-io-authentication-tutorial-server-and-client/ (for Socket.io 0.9)

Hope my answer helps you. Good luck!

Comment: Ty for your answer CuriousGuy. It not solved my problem but Ty for the explanation of the "query" param.
I use socket.io file-upload to upload some images on my web server. In the "update" case, I need to retrieve the image name to assign it on the new image. 
In my console, I saw the connection on my socket is BEFORE my image update action.
Log says, `log input param : undefined` but at this time, I haven't load a new image ...
Please, see my post update. Ty in advance for your help

Comment: +1 ! Ty for your time and your very complete answer. Your solution was my second choice if the `query` parameter did not work. I'll go in that direction. TY CuriousGuy !

Comment: @Curious: How can I pass 2 parameters with query option? Thanks in advance.!

Comment: @Pritam have you tried this: `{query: 'param1=something&param2=another'}` ? You can pass params the same way as you do it with URL GET parameters, i.e. with `&` as a separator

Comment: You are using this in the serverside: `console.log(socket.handshake.query.name);` but I dont understand where is `socket` previously defined...

Comment: @sports my mistake. `socket` is a `'connection'` handler function argument. edited my answer. thank you :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue that ceadreak is facing, I haven't crossed the first stream yet. I am trying to upload an image file using node and socket.io, I am using socketio-file-upload plugin. at **client site** `uploader.listenOnInput(document.getElementById("siofu_input"));` at **server side** am not sure how to get its value, the above answer did not help me.

Comment: Dead link at the end :(

Answer (score 39):

Here's what I've done.

Client

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890',{ query: "foo=bar" });
```

Server

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log(socket.handshake.query['foo']);
});
```

Comment: this is perfect

Comment: This is how it should be. Great (Y)

Comment: Why does this not work for me, what version of socket.io were you using here?

Comment: v4 yout can use this: `var socket = io('http://localhost:8890',{ query: "foo=bar" });`

Answer (score 9):

## In 2021 (socket.io version 4)

```
// client.js

const socket = io('https://195.174.3.104:3000', { query: { myParam: 'myValue' } });
```

```
// server.js

io.on("connection", (socket) => console.log(socket.handshake.query.myParam);  // myValue
```

Source: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#query

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#query