# Socketio query params don't work with more than one namespace

Tags: socket.io

Client side:

```js
const socket = io(
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat?chat=testabc`,
      {
        auth: {
          token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      }
    );
```

However on the server-side in a middleware, I try logging `socket.handshake.query.chat` and I get undefined.

Comment: UPDATE: I have two different namespaces in my backend, I was connecting to the chat namespace in one part of my app, and the notification namespace from another part, when I commented out connecting to the notification namespace, the query params showed up. How would I fix it so I can connect to both namespaces while still showing up query params.

Comment: Refer to this answer for more context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25085538/13708703

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this question while trying to find a solution to the same problem.  Here is what I found.

Even though there are multiple namespaces, `Socket.IO` still uses the same underlying connection between the client and server by default.

On https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#query, the documentation includes a statement:

> The query parameters cannot be updated for the duration of the
> session, so changing the query on the client-side will only be
> effective when the current session gets closed and a new one is
> created:

Since there is only one "session" by default, including query params on a later namespace will be ignored unless you also include the `forceNew: true` property in the connection options which will force a new (second) session to be made to the `Socket.IO` server.

With this *server* code:

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`ID: ${socket.id}; Query: ${JSON.stringify(socket.handshake.query)}`); 
});

io.of('/system').on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`ID: ${socket.id}; Query: ${JSON.stringify(socket.handshake.query)}`); 
});
```

This code on the *client*:

```js
const socket = window.io({query: {x: 42}});
const systemSocket = window.io('/system', {query: {x: 84}});
```

printed:

```text
Query: {"x":"42","EIO":"4","transport":"polling","t":"OFFZihp"}
Query: {"x":"42","EIO":"4","transport":"polling","t":"OFFZihp"} <<-- Wrong Value of x!
```

---

However, after changing the *client* code to:

```js
const socket = window.io({query: {x: 42}});
const systemSocket = window.io('/system', {query: {x: 84}, forceNew: true});
```

it now prints:

```text
Query: {"x":"42","EIO":"4","transport":"polling","t":"OFFaDyR"}
Query: {"x":"84","EIO":"4","transport":"polling","t":"OFFaDyS"} <<-- Now it is correct!
```