# Socket.io 4 with express.js - query parameters missing in onconnection

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, http-proxy-middleware

The `query` object from the client is simply missing from the `handshake` object on the server.

On `console.log(socket)` at the client, `query` object is shown in `_opts` while `opts` looks like -

```
hostname: "localhost"
path: "/socket.io"
port: "3001"
secure: false
```

**CLIENT**

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

this.liveChatSocket = io.connect('/app_chat', {
    transports: 'polling',
    query: {
        patientId,    // string
        type: "patient"
    }
});
```

**setupProxy.js**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        ['/api', '/socket.io'],
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
            changeOrigin: true,
            // agent: {keepAlive: true},
            ws: false,
            logLevel: 'debug'
        })
    );
};
```

**react logs** look like this. Missing query parameters

```
[HPM] POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OrQI-0x&sid=_6nbcQQnHKq5NeQoAAHn -> http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

**SERVER**

**index.js**

```
const makeChatNameSpace = (live_chat) => {
    live_chat.on('any', ()=>console.log("LOG socket.io live_chat any"))

    live_chat.on('connection', function (chatSocket) {

    const { type, patientId, username } = chatSocket.handshake;
    console.log('chat.index.socket_live_chat.on.connection. Type - ', type, 'client - ', type === 'patient' ? patientId : username, 'connected');
}

module.exports.makeChatNameSpace = makeChatNameSpace
```

**www file**

```
let server = http.createServer(app);

const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const { createAdapter } = require("@socket.io/redis-adapter");
const { createClient } = require("redis");

const { makeChatNameSpace } = require("../chat/index");
const { makePersonaNameSpace } = require("../persona/index");

const pubClient = createClient({ url: "redis://localhost:6379" });
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();
pubClient.connect()
subClient.connect()


const io = new Server(server, {
  adapter: createAdapter(pubClient, subClient),
  cors: { origin: "*" }
})

const live_chat = makeChatNameSpace(io.of('/app_chat'))
const persona_builder = makePersonaNameSpace(io.of('/doctor/profile'))    // working, returns void and doesn't have any query parameters

...

module.exports = { io, live_chat, persona_builder }
```

**express logs**
handshake should have the query

```
socket.handshake =  {
  headers: {
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    cookie: '_ga_H66X2LFN0B=GS1.1.1706617189.135.1.1706617196.0.0.0; _ga_37ETJEX8DX=GS1.1.1706617189.127.1.1706617
196.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.1.1585282760.1686473298; sid=s%3ANAkstqaOgBRIAYmaX3P7s38jTTGs-hci.lkF7maU78Z8jxUpMckYGxbbtgMsOF
L1EV%2BfaBJcjfw8; languageSelected=en; io=Knk2BcJ2k6pk7TesAAA2; TCSESSIONID=21B11575713C1D775F8B60FE16151256; _gid
=GA1.1.631497038.1706298581',
    referer: 'http://localhost:3001/',
    connection: 'close',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    accept: '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0',
    host: '127.0.0.1:3000'
  },
  time: 'Tue Jan 30 2024 17:54:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
  address: '::ffff:127.0.0.1',
  xdomain: false,
  secure: false,
  issued: 1706617494246,
  url: '/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OrQL07M',
  query: [Object: null prototype] {
    EIO: '4',
    transport: 'polling',
    t: 'OrQL07M'
  },
  auth: {}
chat.index.socket_live_chat.on.connection. Type -  undefined client -  undefined connected
```

Secondary problem - whenever a new client connects to the server, there's a latency of 20s on 127.0.0.1. Working fine on the nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with using multiple namespaces.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74050501/6944264 explains the detailed problem along with the solution.