# Socket.io my middleware for custom Id does not works

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i followed instructions in this link [Rohit Nishad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61063034/13952358) and my data is well passed from client to server.
But the ID is not passed from my middleware with the overwritten function. A new Generated ID is shown on socket.io connection.

Any idea what's going wrong please ?

I'm using socket.io v3.1.0

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);

const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const io = socketIO(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:4200",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    },
});


// Socket.io configuration
io.of('/notification').use((socket, next) => {
    console.log('(socket.handshake.query.userId) :', socket.handshake.query.userId);
    io.engine.generateId = (req) => {
        socket.handshake.query.userId;
    };
    next(null, true);
});

io.of('/user').use((socket, next) => {
    io.engine.generateId = () => socket.handshake.query.userId;
    next(null, true);
});

io.of('/notification').on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('[Notification] - New client connected : ID ', socket.id);

});
io.of('/user').on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('[User] - New client connected : ID ', socket.id);

});


const serverPort = process.env.PORT || port;

// Launch server

server.listen(serverPort, () => {
    console.log(`App is running ! Go to http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

and console output:

```
App is running ! Go to http://localhost:3000
(socket.handshake.query.userId) : 5ffdb966c204c85d4061bf9f
[Notification] - New client connected : ID  EjdB0uz8K7NSGWYyAAAB
[User] - New client connected : ID  E4tu9sKXliWTFEcsAAAC
```

Comment: where is `io.use()` middelwhere?

Comment: i have added namespace before .use , so my middlewares are io.of('/notification').use((socket, next) and io.of('/user').use((socket, next).
if i dont add the namespace, nothing happens not even a console.log is shown from the middleware

Comment: As I say in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61063034/12247829 this answer you may use `socket.handshake.query.CustomId` or `return socket.handshake.query.CustomId;`. Try both maybe one will work.

Comment: Facing the same issue.